# How do I apply a colormap between minimum and maximum pixel values in image?

Tags: matlab, colorbar, colormap

I have an 8-bit image ('Example_image.tif') that I would like to pseudo-color using custom RGB values from a .csv file ('Pseudocolor_sheet.csv'). The colormap is for pixel values between 0 and 255, however, I would like to apply the all the colors between the *minimum* and *maximum* pixel values present in the image.

Currently, the code yields a grayscale image with the various shades (black/grays/white) applied between the minimum/maximum pixel values. I'm trying to figure out how to apply the colors in this range. Thank you! Here's what I have so far:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

%Choose an image
[filename,filepath] = uigetfile({'C:\Users\'},'Select Example Image','*');
ExampleImage = imread(strcat(filepath, filename));

%Determine minimum & maximum pixel values in image
Min = min(ExampleImage(:))
Min;
Max = max(ExampleImage(:))
Max;

%Display pseudo-colored image
cmap=csvread('pseudocolor_sheet.csv');
imshow(ExampleImage);
colormap(cmap);
colorbar;
caxis([Min, Max]);
```

Comment: Make sure your image is actually gray scale and not an RGB format. The array `ExampleImage` should be 2D, not 3D, for the color map to be applied.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. The example image I'm using is an 8-bit, grayscale image (2D) in TIF format.

Comment: Sometimes images look like grayscale, but when you load them in they turn out as RGB images. Look at the size of the array after loading it in.

Comment: I think the program recognizes it as a grayscale image (it says "1000x1000 uint8"). Also, if I do imshow(ExampleImage,cmap) it pseudocolors the grayscale image using the colormap, just not between minimum/maximum pixel values as I would like to do (maybe a syntax issue). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the [`imshow` documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#d123e182283), to change the display range of colors, you can set the second argument.

`imshow(ExampleImage, []);`

or

`imshow(ExampleImage, [Min Max]);`

or

`imshow(ExampleImage, 'DisplayRange', [Min Max]);`

should do what you want.

Possible alternatives may include using [`imagesc`](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html?s_tid=doc_ta) or using something like `imshow((ExampleImage - Min)/(Max-Min) * 255);`.

Comment: Hi, thank you. According to the documentation, imshow (ExampleImage, [ ]) displays the scaled *grayscale* image based on the range of pixel values. I'd like to do this, but then apply the colormap in that range.

Comment: Ahh ok. If you want a color image try using `imagesc`. You can then set the colormap as you have done.

Comment: Thanks again. I have Matlab 2017a and using "colormap(gca, cmap)" worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out and may be related to my version of Matlab (2017a). I had to add "gca" in the 2nd line below:

```
imshow(ExampleImage, [Min Max]);
colormap(gca, cmap);
colorbar;
```